# how to show div below the link

Tags: jquery, css

Here every thing is working properly, Only the problem is the new_r_div is not showing below the

```
 <a href="#">Response Request</a>'
```

How to do this.

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/QQvv6/30/)

HTML:

```
 <div id="response"> I found this to be a very nice solution. If you had floating children and non floating children, the height will automatically be adjusted to the min amount of space needed. The width is set to 100% to expand to the
this is a
   <a href="#">Response Request</a>
   <div class="new_r_div">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="link" >Confirm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link" >Delete</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .new_r_div{
   position:absolute;
   width:100px;
   height:40px;
   background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
   border: solid 2px #ccc;
 background: #99CCFF;
  z-index: 9999;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
 visibility: hidden;
}

#response:hover .new_r_div
 {
   visibility: visible;
}
   .new_r_div li:hover{
      background:red;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean, you add `visibility: hidden;` in `.new_r_div`

Comment: on load .new_r_div will be hidden

Comment: And in your jsfiddle, move mouse in `#response`, it will display. And what's your problem?

Comment: It should desplay below the link

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using jQuery.. Just add the following jQuery to your code..

```
$(function(){ setDiv(); });  //Executes on refresh
$(window).resize(function () { setDiv();});  //Executes on page resize

function setDiv(){
    var aLeft = $('#response>a').offset().left;
    $('.new_r_div').css({'left' : aLeft});
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/33/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like => jsfiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/32/).

You have to make some changes in css as shown.

```
.new_r_div {
    display:inline-block;   
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:-102px; 
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;   
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
    background: #99CCFF;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```